# Error: The code should be running in the fakeAsync zone to call this function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run my test case which is throwing this exception with jasmine.

Below is my test case where I am just trying to check whether the object is created or not.

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let service: MyService;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule        
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [MyService]
    }).compileComponents();
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    service =  TestBed.inject(MyService)
    
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    flush();
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  it('should create the app', fakeAsync(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'My Sample App';
  dataSelected: string = "";

 
constructor(private service: MyService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getData(this.dataSelected);
  }

}
```

**my.filter.service.ts**

```
export class MyService {

  availableData: BehaviorSubject<string[]> | undefined;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    let emptyArray :string[] = [];
    this.availableData = new BehaviorSubject(emptyArray);
  }

  getData(data: string){
   this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/getData", 
      {"name": data}).subscribe(respData => {
        let resp: string[] = Object.values(respData);
      this.availableData?.next(resp);
      console.log("Data fetched from server");
    });
  }
}
```

**Error-Information**

```
Error: The code should be running in the fakeAsync zone to call this function
Error: The code should be running in the fakeAsync zone to call this function
    at _getFakeAsyncZoneSpec (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:2072:1)
    at Object.flush (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:2105:1)
    at flush (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/testing.js:372:1)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:33:10)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:372:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.push.QpwO.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:301:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:371:1)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:134:1)
    at runInTestZone (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:581:1)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:596:1)
```

Please help me with some possible solutions that works here.

Comment: You should either be testing the component (mocking the service) or testing the service, mocking the HttpClient. Also the best practice for this kind of setup is to have the service return the Observable generated by HttpClient and subscribe to it in the component. It will make structuring your tests easier.

Comment: Can you please explain, I couldn't get what you are trying to explain?
Any sample code might help greately.

Comment: When unit testing a component, you shouldn't pass the real service. You should pass a mock (generally a spy).

Comment: In Angular architecture, when a service makes an HTTP call, you don't subscribe to the Observable in the service. The service method should return the Observable, and the component (or other service) subscribes. This means you don't have weird asynchronous issues that make testing a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is related to [`flush()`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/flush) used inside the `afterEach` function.

```
afterEach(() => {
  flush();
  httpMock.verify();
});
```

You can probably simply remove it since there's no async stuff in your test so far.